# checking, operation successful after any LinqToSql operation

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We normally use these statements to add anew record to database.

```
MyDataContext.InsertOnSubmit(AnObject);
MyDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Other than using stored procedure(can return a value by "Return / Output"), is there a way to return a value indicating, operation was successful ? probably, Linq own methods / functions

Any idea, Thanks

Comment: Be sure to mark the correct answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the operation is not successful, then it will throw an exception. If it doesn't throw an exception, then it was successful.

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`

Comment: Whatever exception caused the operation to fail. I would not assume it would be `SqlException`.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't use a try and catch block and trap the appropriate errors?

Comment: Thanks for reply, It is not about failing a transaction, actually want to check an operation was successful, like doing an Update. It might not update and not fail either...

Comment: You would get an exception related to the update operation failure.